# Convert dollar to any currency

Tags: javascript, regex

I am still a newbie in regular expression, please help me out guys.

I have this html file, some of the paragraphs contains dollar values ($200, $300 etc). Whenever a user visits that file it will convert those values into their own currency.

I want to use regular expression to look for those values and have proper conversion.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the connection between currency conversion and regex?

Comment: Conversion rates are fixed by yourself? Or you retrieve them using some external service?

Comment: but you're gonna do proper rate conversion or just change the $ with for example an € char ?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan, yes I have an external source. all I need is to get those dollar values and convert it.

Comment: @BigMike, it's easy to search and replace the $ to €. but I find hard to look for words that has the $ sign and must be a number or decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example with few assumptions. I believe you have the conversion factor and you can substitute the actual value with the conversion factor.

**Edit: modified to allow conversion only for the matching numerical values. Numerical values are assumed to be positive integer values.**

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/eBQFE/

**Example:**

- Converted from currency "$" to hypothetical currency with symbol "@"
- Conversion factor: 0.05

**Input**

> $200 some $100 content goes $300 here

**Output**

> @10 some @5 content goes @15 here

```
 function convert() {
     var replacedText = document.getElementById('myPara').innerText;
     var newCurrencySymbol = '@';
     var currencyConversionFactor = 0.05;
     var numberPattern = /\$\d+/g;
     var numbers = replacedText.match(numberPattern);
     for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
         // extract numerical value
         var num = numbers[i].match(/\d+/);
         // your currency conversion here
         var newNum = newCurrencySymbol + (num * currencyConversionFactor);
         replacedText = replacedText.replace(numbers[i], newNum);
     }
     document.getElementById('convertedPara').innerText = replacedText;
 }
```

Comment: The hash id in your jsfiddle url is bit offensive :P

Comment: I didn't notice.. that is autogenerated  :)

Comment: @macek, Created a new fiddle :)